# Unable to install ROS in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am unable to install ROS on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Below is the error I am facing

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/4b82b30994acfd18785cbf9ea5914c6f

is it the problem of the ubuntu version or did I miss anything I have followed all steps provided in the installation guide any help is highly appreciated

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/158001/unable-to-install-ros-in-ubuntu-14.04-lts/) by [Raghu Parvatha](https://answers.ros.org/users/15256/raghu-parvatha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-04-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hydro not supported for ubuntu 14.04 try to install [indigo](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu)

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2014-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2014-04-27**:
Indigo isn't officially released yet either. I had success installing ros_comm from source and installing the rest through apt-get.

**Comment by [Raghu Parvatha](https://answers.ros.org/users/15256/raghu-parvatha/) on 2014-04-28**:
Hansg91 can you please help me  in installation process.

**Comment by [Raghu Parvatha](https://answers.ros.org/users/15256/raghu-parvatha/) on 2014-04-28**:
hamid thank you for your reply but as Hansg said even I am unable to install the package I am getting below error message admin@admin:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-desktop-full

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-04-28**:
ros-indigo-desktop-full is not available yet. For now, you can just do

sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-*

It'll have far more packages than you'll probably want/need, but you'll be sure to have everything. :)

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2014-04-28**:
did you update your sources.list?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-04-28**:
The from source instructions should work on 14.04 unless there are problems compiling against newer versions of libraries in 14.04: http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Source However hydro isn't supported for 14.04, so it may not work without some debugging.